# Nanoframework STM32 Nucleo_F103RB E5006

Tags: stm32, nanoframework

Recently, I learned about NanoFF. I am using the STM32 Nucleo_F103RB evaluation board. I am trying to configure everything, and I have encountered an issue while uploading the image to the STM.

I am attempting to use the "nanoff --target ST_NUCLEO64_F091RC --update" command. (It seems to me that ST_NUCLEO64_F091RC is the closest to my STM, but I may be mistaken.)

After using the command, I receive the message "Error E5006: Failed to write new firmware to the device." What should I do to resolve this issue? The STM was previously used. Could the error be caused by the flasher not removing the previous program from memory?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjmTR.png)

I searched the documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: STM32F0 and STM32F1 are quite different MCUs, and doubtless have different flash sizes. You could try `nanoff --listtargets --platform stm32` and see if there is a better match.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Thank you for response. 
After entering this command, I received these devices:
ORGPAL_PALTHREE
ST_NUCLEO64_F091RC
ST_STM32F429I_DISCOVERY
ST_STM32F769I_DISCOVERY
PybStick2x
NETDUINO3_WIFI
ST_NUCLEO0144_F746ZG
ST_STM32F4_DISCOVERY
ST_NUCLEO144_F439ZI
ST_NUCLEO64_F401RE_NF
ST_NUCLEO144_F412ZG_NF
ST_STM32F411_DISCOVERY
ST_NUCLEO64_F411RE_NF
NESHTEC_NESHNODE_V1
WEACT_F411CE
I2M_ELECTRON_NF
GHI_FEZ_CERB40_NF
BrainPad2
MBN_QUAIL
I2M_OXYGEN_NF
GHI_FEZ_CERBERUS_NF
Which of these will be the most suitable for my STM? Where can I check which ones will be compatible?

Comment: Definitely you can't use the firmware image of STM32F091 on your device. There is no firmware for the F1 series, although the series is supported by the build system.
You can find a list with the official firmware packages here:

https://github.com/nanoframework/Home?tab=readme-ov-file#firmware-for-reference-boards

and the community provided ones here:
https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Community-Targets?tab=readme-ov-file#available-community-boards